# SwiftUI save PDF to files from remote using PDFKit

Tags: pdf, swiftui, pdfkit

I've tried to save PDF file from link with **ActivityViewController** by clicking **Save File** using **PDFKit**. But I found problem that my file for some reason comes as **filename.txt**

Below provided **documentsView**, which shows document's list.
By clicking **SAVE**, starts saveAction, which contains documentName and URL

```
private var documentsView: some View{
        Group{
            Section(header: CustomHeaderView(title: sectionTitle)) {
                ForEach(viewModel.documents, id: \.self){ document in
                    VStack(spacing: 7){
                        DocumentRow(title: document.title ?? "", action: { saveAction(for: document) })
                    }
                }
                .sheet(isPresented: $isSavePresented){
                    ActivityViewController(activityItems: ["MyFileName" , pdfDocument])
                }
            }
        }
    }

private func saveAction(for document: PolicyDocument){
    guard let url = document.uRL else { return }
    guard let urlObject = URL(string: url) else { return }
    if let doc =  PDFDocument(url: urlObject){
        pdfDocument = doc
        isSavePresented.toggle()
    }
}

struct ActivityViewController: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
var activityItems: [Any]
var applicationActivities: [UIActivity]? = nil

func makeUIViewController(context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<ActivityViewController>) -> UIActivityViewController {
    let controller = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: activityItems, applicationActivities: applicationActivities)
    return controller
}

func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: UIActivityViewController, context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<ActivityViewController>) {}

}
```

**SOLVED**

by adding **.dataRepresentation()!** to pdfDocument

Comment: If it's solved, you can add an answer to your question and mark it as resolved.

Comment: @jnpdx done, so stupid solution... why I didn't check it earlier(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

solved by adding **.dataRepresentation()** to file itself. Did with guard, just posting example below...

Example:

```
.sheet(isPresented: $isSavePresented){
      ActivityViewController(activityItems: ["MyFileName" , pdfDocument.dataRepresentation()!])
}
```